# Hide status bar in SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I've been trying to hide the status bar in `SWRevealViewController`,but hiding status bar shouldn't effect the other `UIViewController`, it should only hide it where Sliding-Menu opens only. to hide the text and the date etc.. !

I've tried the following :

```
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

But the status bar colour just changed to while colour and still unhidden ! 
I've no idea how is it possible to do ?

Comment: do you use storyboards?

Comment: for sure yes ,first the SWRevealViewController -> Empty UIViewController, which is connected to rear_view -> MenuController as UITableViewController.

Comment: If you want to hide the status bar in all controllers then you should see the link below it will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/how-to-hide-ios-7-status-bar

Answer (score 0):

set the `statusBarHidden` property to be `true` before `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true`

If you don't want the status bar hide in other views. You can show the status bar before your view disappear in `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: This is gonna make a problem, because I'm having navigation controller on the UIViewController, and on the menu i don't have a navigation controller but only status bar. so when i navigate to the menu it also hides the status bar in the UIViewController which shouldn't happen.

Comment: @AaoIi Did you set the `statusBarHidden` to be `false` before navigation? Or you can try to do that in the view without navigationbar

Comment: @AaoIi Did the status bar show in the view without navigation bar before?

Comment: What happened exactly when i navigated to the SWRevealViewController, the status bar of the Old UIViewController hides without the Navigation Controller, and in the SWRevealViewController the status bar is hidden. and when i navigate back to the UIViewController the status bar comes back from top sliding ..

Answer (score 0):

hide it when the menu is coming up:

```
//delegate method
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position {
    BOOL rm = position != FrontViewPositionLeft;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:rm withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}
```

for the code to work set this in your plist:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance to NO
(UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance)
```

Comment: This doesn't work too, we should play with childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden and childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle . but I've no idea how is it possible to do !

Comment: edited - new way - tested and works. the revealer already implements `childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle` -- without that my 'old' way would have worked

Comment: It makes this issue again : What happened exactly when i navigated to the SWRevealViewController, the status bar of the Old UIViewController hides without the Navigation Controller, and in the SWRevealViewController the status bar is hidden. and when i navigate back to the UIViewController the status bar comes back from top sliding ..

Comment: yes sure.. it animates out and in and that looks bad :) but thats what you wanted

Comment: I answered the question.. if it were me I wouldn't do it :D

Comment: my question is hiding the status bar of the menu without effecting the other UIViewControllers status bar too :)

Comment: then I didn't get that :)

Comment: You may check the gmail app on App Store and see what i mean when you open the menu and the status bar. you'll get what i mean !

Comment: please note I haven't/won't download the gmail app just for this ;)

Comment: oh Yeah ! I'm just trying and testing, :D

Comment: I've tried it but it still showing, have a look here : [the image here](http://i921.photobucket.com/albums/ad53/Johann_1990/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-23%20at%2012.25.30%20PM.png)

Comment: @AaoIi I am having the same problem. Did you figured out problem and found the solution? Thanks

Comment: @virusss8 check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38636410/3989689 , you only need to place it in viewWilAppear and viewDidDisappear of your side menu vc.

Comment: @AaoIi I founded another one. Somehow constraints in menuTableView was broken, and with snapKit, I just set constraints to 0 to self.view. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I put this in LeftMenuViewController and HomeViewController.

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
  return YES;
}
```

---

for example, I put the following in AppDelegate.m.
And LeftMenuViewController means viewController for "the left menu".

```
HomeViewController *home = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
LeftMenuViewController *leftMenu = [[LeftMenuViewController alloc]init];

UINavigationController *mainNC =
[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:home];

UINavigationController *menuNC =
[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:leftMenu];

_revealVC = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRearViewController:menuNC
                                                  frontViewController:mainNC];
self.window.rootViewController = _revealVC;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```